# ParseObject.put method saving strings etc as arrays? Is this a bug?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I try to save simple Object attibutes using the .put("name", data) method

```
 ParseObject parseLibraryItem = new ParseObject("UserLibrary");
            parseLibraryItem.add("movieId", 121);
            parseLibraryItem.add("runtime", 134);
            parseLibraryItem.add("status", "released");
            parseLibraryItem.add("name", "TestParseMovie");
            parseLibraryItem.add("releaseDate", "2014-11-06");
            parseLibraryItem.add("imagePath", "/7k9db7pJyTaVbz3G4eshGltivR1.jpg");
            parseLibraryItem.add("description", "This is just a test");
            parseLibraryItem.add("tagline", "The craziest movie ever");
            parseLibraryItem.add("createdBy", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
            parseLibraryItem.setACL(new ParseACL(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()));
            parseLibraryItem.saveInBackground();
```

Here is the Parse backend
[image: You can clearly see each item is an array]

When I try to query the Object I have to then strip the returned string of the Brackets. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: We cannot see the content of `description` in the code you posted. However, if you by mistake added an array or list as description the very first time you added an object, then the column is locked to that data type. To reset the type you would have to remove the column and either add a new object that introduces the ´description´ column, or add it manually in the data browser.

Comment: I made a small mistake. Was testing to see if a String reference would work but no it still goes in as an Array. I deleted the objects and did it again and its still array?

Comment: Look at the imagePath, movieId and name. All as arrays even though in the code its just in " "

Comment: Deleting the objects won't make a difference, you must delete the columns. Alternatively you can delete the class entirely, or rename 'UserLibrary' to something else to try it out.

Comment: Made a new object class called ItemTest1. Still columns are listed as arrays! Here is a link to my entire project. Takes place in the MainActivity towards the bottom

Comment: Another strange thing is that this line
                    parseLibraryItem.add("createdBy", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

outputs this [{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"nMA8R34bzJ"}]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the method add(String key, Object value), which atomically adds an object to the end of the array associated with a given key, try using the method put(String key, Object value), which adds a key-value pair to this object.

source : Android Parse API https://parse.com/docs/android/api/